# Rails 3 RESTful Authentication - uninitialized constant ApplicationController::AuthenticatedSystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication

Just installed the upgraded restful_authentication plugin for Rails 3 from https://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication. I'm trying to include code from the plugin in my application helper as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    include AuthenticatedSystem
end
```

However, when I run the server and navigate to my application on the localhost, I get an error as follows:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::AuthenticatedSystem
```

AuthenticatedSystem is a module in lib/authenticated_system.rb, so why isn't the include working?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails 3 doesn't load files in the /lib directory by default anymore :(

Add this to your config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

And you should be fine. Don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Any idea about the reasoning for why it's not included by default anymore?